# use of external dependencies in pipeline shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to understand how to import external dependencies into jenkins for use in pipeline shared library?
 For example, in my library I would like to use the retrofit2. I tried to add a jar file retrofit in *jenkins/jre/lib/* and in *jenkins/workflow-libs/* but it did not help.I get the error *unable to resolve class retrofit.Callback*

Comment: That's documented in the global shared libary documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use groovy's dependency solution: [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html)

Example

```
 @Grab(group='com.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='3.3')
```